Scroll restore location functionality problem in mobile view
I have implemented a scroll restore location functionality that gets me back to the same location and it is working fine in the desktop view but it takes me to the top of the page in mobile view. I am using Next
Code:
const scrollToLastAssignment = useCallback(() => {
    const lastAssignmentId = localStorage.getItem("lastAssignmentId");
    console.log(
      "Attempting to scroll to Last Assignment ID:",
      lastAssignmentId
    );
    if (lastAssignmentId) {
      const element = document.getElementById(lastAssignmentId);
      if (element && element.offsetParent !== null) {
        // Check if element is visible
        console.log("Element found, scrolling to:", lastAssignmentId);
        element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
        console.log("Siddhya");
      } else {
        console.error("Element not found:", lastAssignmentId);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("No assignment ID found.");
    }
  }, [tableData]);
 

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [getData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollToLastAssignment();
  }, [tableData, scrollToLastAssignment]);


Please help!
I am facing the same issue if I reduce the size of my desktop browser.
